# Slightly confused about the definition of upper limits and lower limits.

Tags: analysis, limits

I'm reading "The way of Analysis" by Strichartz, and the following is the definition of an upperlimit.

> The upper limit (limsup) of a sequence $\{x_j\}$ is the extended real number 
>   $$\limsup _{k \to \infty} x_k = \lim_{k \to \infty }\sup_{j>k} x_j$$.

I am confused about the left side of the equality.

My understanding is, a limit point $x$ of a sequence $\{x_j\}$ is a point where for any given $\epsilon >0$ there exists infinitely many terms $x_j$ such that
$$|x-x_j|< \epsilon$$.

Another thing that I think I understand is that if $y_k = \sup_{j>k}x_j$, $\{y_k\}$ becomes a monotonic sequence where if we take $k \to \infty$ $\{y_k\} \to y$ where $y$ is not only a limit point, but the supremum of the set of limitpoints of $\{x_j\}$.

So I am thinking, the right side of the equation represents the "limit of the supremum of the subsequences" which is intuitively clear to me, but I don't get the left side. What does it mean ?

Since I am not too good at analysis, I will appreciate your help a lot if you could dumb down your explanation.

Comment: The LHS is introducing notation, defined by the RHS. A possible exercise is to prove that the limsup is also the sup of all limits of convergent subsequences of $\{x_k\}$.

Comment: So, how do I consider the left side ? Is it the supremum of the limit of $x_k$ ?

Comment: No, no. It's notation. As I said, the RHS *is the definition*.

Comment: Are you saying that here, "limsup of $x_k$ as $k \to \infty$" is defined as the RHS ?

Comment: YES! You even said it in what you typed :)

Comment: Thank you ! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper limit just means taking the "limit" of all supremums of a sequence. So if you have $$1,2,3,4,299,199,5,6,....198,198,198,....$$then $299$ would be included in the supremum of all subsequence start from $a_{i},i\le 4$; $199$ would be included in the supremum of the subsequence start from $a_{5}$; and once we pass $a_{5}$ the limit become $198$, which is the "true" upper limit of the whole sequence when we ignore the lower order terms.

Write in symbols, $c$ is the upper limit means for any $\epsilon$, there exist some $N$ such that for any $n\ge N$, we have the supremum of the subsequence $\langle a_{n}\rangle$ (define it as $b_{n}$) satisfying $|b_{n}-c|<\epsilon$. So $a_{n}$ may still be slightly higher than $c$, but as $n\to \infty$ we would observe $a_{n}$ goes "down" to "under" $c$.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense. So the LHS means the limit of the supremum of $x_k$ and the RHS means the supremum of the limit points of $\{x_j\}$, right ?

Comment: I think this is a notional ambiguity. When he write $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sup x_{k}$, he means the limit of supremum of the subsequence begin from $x_{k}$ when $k$ goes to $\infty$. This is what the equal sign means.